# JQCloud - space out words in the cloud

Tags: javascript, jquery

Recently I began to use JQCloud to create word clouds. It works perfectly but the words are too close to each other since I use a small amount of words.

I was wondering if there is a way to space out the words in the cloud ?

Comment: Have you find a solution?